# Is it setting min-width of html, body is safe (for planning children min-width)?

Tags: html, css

I want design some layout in which ,  has defined min-width - is it safe?

Can I use @media (max-width) to define different ,  min-width on different devices?

I am focusing on modern browsers Chrome, Fire Fox, Safari, Windows 8 IE - computers, tablers, smartphones (Android, iOS)?

Comment: may i sure try min-width:100%;

Answer (score 1):

Are you are serving a separate mobile site or styling an existing desktop version with media queries? For the former use Chrome inspector to set the user agent to emulate the most common Android phones. For the latter use max-width and/or device-pixel ratios for your displays. It is essential to get the breakpoints right for the mobile display or your layout will collapse.

See [CSS tricks to get a good starting point](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Answer (score 0):

Dont use a min or max width on a body, just use a wrapper div around the content and a header div around the header and navigation.( if you have the navigation like a stip under the header)

Comment: You are inaccurate - max-width is not on body and min-width on body is ok same like on html - it not mean that min-width on body and html will be same on all screen (for mobile it can different).